# how to check the return value of a lambda inside an if statement in c++?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm working on a small snake game challenge using only the console window, and I got stuck in the draw function where the console is supposed to get cleared, and then draw the grid and the other componements (snake, tail and fruit)

and this is the code:

```
void draw()
{
   system("cls");

   for(int h = 0;h < HEIGHT;h++)
   {
       for(int w = 0;w < WIDTH ; w++)
       {
           if(h == snake.y && w == snake.x)std::cout << snake.symbol;
           else if(        [&](){for(Snake::Tail T : snake.tails)
                           {if(T.x == w && T.y == h)return true;}return false;}
                            == true)
           {std::cout << snake.tailSymbol;}


           else if(h == fruit.y && w == fruit.x)std::cout << fruit.symbol;
           else std::cout << "O";
       }
       std::cout << "\n";
   }

}
```

it may seem confusing but what this does it loop through each position in the grid and check first if the snake (the head of the snake) is at that position,

else it goes through a loop of all the tails conected to the snake USING A LAMBDA

the rest is not important but the problem is that I had to use a lambda in order  to merge the if statement and the for loop together without breaking the "else" chain, but the problem is that when I try to check if the lambda return true or false I get the error:

```
...Snake\main.cpp|40|error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'draw()::<lambda()>' and 'bool')|
```

my experience with lambda in c++ is not that solid yet but I still want to use lambda rather than a function, how can I fix the error and check the value ?

Comment: Not a C++ expert, but why not defining a function and calling it in your "if chain" ? That would be far easier to read and would meet the same purpose.

Comment: 1) There is little point to create and then directly invoke a lambda as shown; 2) The code fails given a lambda like `auto l = []{ return true; };` when used as `bool x = l == true;` because it attempts to compare the lambda to true (which is not allowed by default) vs. `bool x = l() == true;` which _invokes_ the lambda and uses the boolean result.

Comment: @NoDataFound I know that would be easier but I prefer the hard way for the sake of learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a lambda expression to a `bool`, which is not allowed. You need to call the lambda and compare the result you get, like this:

```
else if ([&]() {
             for (Snake::Tail T : snake.tails) {
                 if (T.x == w && T.y == h)
                     return true;
             }
             return false;
         }() // call it
    == true)
```

There are several simplifications you could do. For starters, the comparison to `bool` with `== true` is redundant, and doesn't help readability. The `for` loop can be replaced by an algorithm, like this:

```
else if ([&]() {
             return std::any_of(snake_tails.begin(), snake_tails.end(),
                 [&](auto T) {
                     return T.x == w && T.y == h;
                 });
         }())
```

Since you're now just returning a single value from the lambda, you could drop the lambda entirely, and simply use the return value:

```
else if (std::any_of(snake_tails.begin(), snake_tails.end(),
             [&](auto T) {
                 return T.x == w && T.y == h;
             }))
```

Comment: this looks even weirder but if the compiler say it works then who am I to argue, thanks for the help

Comment: Worse, a non-capturing lambda can compare to bool, via the conversion to pointer-to-function. But the body will not be evaluated and the result will always be as though the lambda were true.

Comment: No problem. Is it the formatting that looks weird, or the fact that you need an extra `()`?

Comment: it's the extra (), as I said I'm not used to using lambda so the way the whole lambda is structured looks alien to me

Comment: The `[](){}` part is the lambda expression, which is a function ready to be invoked. The final `()` actually invokes it,jjust llike `f()` would.

Comment: I also noticed that writing a lambda like this  ` [](){}` doesn't generate any compiling error